# Double Integrals and finding the volume of a pool

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the volume of a pool and Im a little rusty on the calculus.
How would I go about finding the volume of pool that is Length 10ft by Width 8ft? The depth goes from 3 to 6 feet with a slope of 3ft/10ft.

Comment: You don't need calculus for this. It can be done with simple geometry.

Comment: How do I do that? you didn't answer anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pool is a cuboid of length $10$ ft breadth $8$ ft and height $3$ ft placed over an inverted wedge of dimensions base length $10$ ft, base breadth $8$ ft and height $3$ ft.

Thus, volume of the pool is the volume of the cuboid plus the volume of the inverted wedge i.e,

$$V_{\text{pool}}  = V_{\text{cuboid}} + V_{\text{inverted wedge}}$$

$$(8\times 10\times 3) + (\frac{1}{2} \times 8 \times 10 \times 3)$$
$$ = 360 \text{ ft}^3$$

I guess if you really wanted it in terms of integration then we can derive these volumes via integration.

The area of the cross section of the wedge is given by $$\int_{0}^{8}\frac{3}{8}ydy$$

And the volume will be the integration of this cross section over the base length i.e.

$$V_{\text{inverted wedge}} = \int_{0}^{10}\left(\int_{0}^{8}\frac{3}{8}ydy\right)dx$$

You can do the same for a cuboid. You should get

$$V_{\text{cuboid}} = \int_{0}^{10}\left(\int_{0}^{8}3dy\right)dx$$

Comment: thank you! is there any way to solve this using integration? I feel like there should be some way to find this using integration.